ngx-color-picker module close when change color
I have used ngx-color-picker module in the angular mat-menu content but issue is when open color-picker module and change color, then why is the color-picker module closed I have checked and issue is for the angular mat-menu , How to resolved this becuase i need color-picker module in the mat-menu section
<mat-menu #gradientPopup="matMenu" yPosition="above" xPosition="before" [overlapTrigger]="false" class="text-gradient-popup">
 <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation();" id="cnvs_grd_menu">
  <div class="gredient-spead-items d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center my-2 txt-geadient-clr-picker h-55 position-relative"
                      *ngFor="let clr of gradientArray; let i = index; trackBy: trackBgGradient">
                      <div type="text" class="form-control color-input pull-right custom-picker" [cpPosition]="'bottom'"
                        [cpOutputFormat]="'hex'" [(colorPicker)]="clr.color" id="{{'grd_clr'+i}}"
                        [style.background]="clr.color" (cpSliderDragEnd)="changeGradientColor(clr.color,i)" (cpInputChange)="changeGradientColor(clr.color,i)" 
                        [cpIgnoredElements]="['.mat-menu-content']"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</mat-menu>



You should try to recreate your issue in a stackblitz and link to that for debugging

Another approaches
